# Nginx is refusing to connect on AWS EC2

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use nginx to setup a simple node.js server, I'm running the server in background on port 4000, my nginx config file is

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name 52.53.196.173;
  location / {
    include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
  }
}
```

I saved it in /etc/nginx/sites-available and also symlinked it to sites-enabled, the nginx.conf file has the include line already to load files from sites-enabled, then i restarted the service using
    sudo service nginx restart
I tried going to 52.53.196.173 and it refuses to connect, however going to 52.53.196.173:4000 with port 4000 it is working, but I'm trying to make it listen on port 80 with nginx, i tried putting my .ml domain as server_name and no luck, and i have the IP 52.53.196.173 as the A record in the domain dns settings, and I'm doing this on an AWS EC2 Instance Ubuntu Server 16.04, i even tried the full ec2 public dns url no luck, any ideas?

Edit: I solved it by moving the file directly in sites-enabled instead of a symlink

Answer (score 4):

There is few possible things. First of all you need to verify that nginx server is running & listening on port 80. you can check the listening ports using the following command.

```
netstat -tunlp
```

Then you need to check your server firewall & also the selinux policies. ( OR disable selinux for test )

Then you need to verify that AWS security group configured to access the http/https connections on port 80.

PS : Outputs from the following command & configurations will be helpful for troubleshooting.

```
netstat -tunlp
sestatus
iptables -L

* AWS Security Group Rules
* Nginx configurations ( including main configuration if changed )
```

P.S : OP fixed the problem by moving the config file directly into **site-enabled** directory. maybe, reefer the comments for more info if you are having the same issue.

Comment: netstat output https://hastebin.com/ehetegoxif.nginx
AWS Security groups https://i.imgur.com/md7rlNn.png i didn't touch main nginx configuration (nginx.conf)

Comment: Seems like there is nothing listening on port 80. can you post the nginx configuration for specific application ?

and the service status of the nginx service ?

Comment: For output of sudo service nginx status https://hastebin.com/amawezikap.rb and what do you mean by "configuration for specific application" i did post the nginx file i use in the question

Comment: did you delete the nginx.conf file ?

Comment: can you post nginx.conf ? I saw the your application specific configuration bit after the comment. sorry, my bad :/

Comment: just put your site specific nginx configuration file into **sites-enabled** ( not symlinked - to test )

Comment: add this configuration directly to **site-enabled** and try. :-)

[https://pastebin.com/Jv4TtHGd]

Comment: Dude thanks a lot, moving the file directly to sites-enabled instead of a symlink seemed to fix it, now i can request to port 80 and responds! Thanks a lot i spent half of my day googling and this fixed it.

Comment: In my case the issue was because I made the classic mistake of not putting ".conf" at the end of my site config files. I realised this after seeing that nothing was listening on port 80 with running `netstat -tunlp`, so thanks for helping me to resolve this!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably port 80 might not be open in your security group or nginx is not running to accept the connections. Please post the nginx status and check the security group

Comment: Ports r fine, when i first installed nginx the default configuration welcome page loaded but when i deleted it and added my own it doesn't work now

Comment: do a test using tcpdump on port 80 when you request the page by typing the ip address in url. this will tell if the request is coming to port 80 of the server or not. `tcpdump -i eth0 'port 80'` where eth0 is the ethernet card interface on your server.

Comment: I have no idea what is ethernet cards

Comment: if you type ifconfig in the shell prompt and it will give you the name of your ethernet interface.. usually its always eth0

Comment: I did the tcpdump thing and yes i did recieve some packets

Comment: please post the output of nginx log file too

Comment: Turned out to be true, This was a very useful hint.

Answer (score 1):

check belows:

1. in security group, add Http (80) and Https (443) in inbound section with 0.0.0.0 ip as follow:

for `80` :

[image]

for `443` :

[image]

2. in Network ACL, allow inbound on http and https. outbound set custom TCP role as follow:

inbound roles:

[image]

outbound roles:

[image]

3. assign a elastic ip on ec2 instance, listen to this ip for public.